# Orange Pi Zero 3 WiFi Access Point Broken using Ubuntu Image

Tags: ubuntu, networking, hostapd

**Problem**

I created a Bridge Access Point using Orange Pi Zero 3 with the Ubuntu OS. However, after going through a fairly lengthy configuration, there is an issue when trying to connect to my Orange Pi Zero 3 Access Point.

The problem is: it gets stuck at 'authenticate,' and there is no pop-up to enter the password on my smartphone.

**Configuration**

Setting file system /etc/network/interfaces

```
# Network is managed by Network manager
#auto lo
#iface lo inet loopback
#
#Eth Static Configuration
#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp # HiBob Configuration
#    address 192.168.6.55
#    netmask 255.255.255.0
#    gateway 192.168.6.254
#    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
#
#Wlan0 Static Configuration
#auto wlan0
#allow-hotplug wlan0
#iface wlan0 inet manual
#wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
#iface default inet static
#    address -
#    netmask 255.255.255.0
#    gateway 192.168.6.254
#
#Access Point Configuration
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
# Eth0 Configuration
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
# Wlan0 Configuration
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
#wireless power off
# Br0 Configuration
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
address 192.168.6.55
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.6.254
bridge_ports eth0 wlan0
bridge_fd 0
bridge_stp off
```

Setting file system /etc/hostapd.conf

```
#
# orangepi hostapd configuration example
#
# nl80211 mode
#

ssid=HBGateway
interface=wlan0
hw_mode=g
channel=40
bridge=br0
driver=nl80211

logger_syslog=0
logger_syslog_level=0
wmm_enabled=1
wpa=2
preamble=1

wpa_psk=66eb31d2b48d19ba216f2e50c6831ee11be98e2fa3a8075e30b866f4a5ccda27
wpa_passphrase=6666666666
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
auth_algs=1
macaddr_acl=0

### IEEE 802.11n
ieee80211n=1
ht_capab=[SHORT-GI-20][SHORT-GI-40][HT40+]
country_code=ID
ieee80211d=1
### IEEE 802.11n

### IEEE 802.11a
hw_mode=a
### IEEE 802.11a

### IEEE 802.11ac
ieee80211ac=1
#vht_capab=[MAX-MPDU-11454][SHORT-GI-80][TX-STBC-2BY1][RX-STBC-1][MAX-A-MPDU-LEN-EXP3]
vht_oper_chwidth=1
vht_oper_centr_freq_seg0_idx=42
### IEEE 802.11ac

# controlling enabled
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
```

**Result Configuration**

ifconfig result

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.6.55  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.6.255
        inet6 fe80::a84f:ff:fec0:5cc8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether aa:4f:00:c0:5c:c8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8075  bytes 1468199 (1.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1316  bytes 162441 (162.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:00:08:3d:19:71  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8118  bytes 1588035 (1.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 41  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1316  bytes 162441 (162.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 43

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 10  bytes 1612 (1.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10  bytes 1612 (1.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether f8:b4:76:a0:3d:7b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1687  bytes 276151 (276.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**Question**

I have used this configuration on Orange Pi Zero 2, and it worked successfully. There are around 100 devices running in production using this setup. However, when I tried to apply the same configuration to Orange Pi Zero 3, it failed, and I haven't found many forums discussing it yet. Could it be because Orange Pi Zero 3 is still relatively new?

How can I resolve this issue? I've heard there are quite a few bugs in the Ubuntu OS for Orange Pi Zero 3.

OS Ubuntu Download : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CJYrhHyyje9dEY4-t7JhcZBJfdAFBJro?usp=drive_link

Orangepizero3_1.0.2_ubuntu_jammy_desktop_xfce_linux6.1.31